# How to call an external JavaScript function in Ionic 2

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2

I have a JavaScript method in an external JS file. In an Ionic 2 project, I have to call some methods of `AnyJS` function from my `home.ts`. I have included the JS file inside a `<script>` tag in `index.html`. I have declared `AnyJS` like this `declare var AnyJS: any;` above `@Component` in my `home.ts`.

Now, while creating an object by using the `new` keyword in the constructor I'm getting the following reference error:

> 5     713568   error    EXCEPTION: Error in ./HomePage class HomePage_Host - inline template:0:0 caused by: AnyJS is not defined
>   6     713570   error    ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: AnyJS is not defined
>   8     713575   error    `ReferenceError: AnyJS is not defined`

The Ionic version I'm using:

```
Cordova CLI: 6.3.1
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.1
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.0
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.0-beta.1
ios-deploy version: 1.8.3 
ios-sim version: 5.0.4 
OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v6.8.0
Xcode version: Xcode 8.0 Build version 8A218a
```

Here is the `home.ts`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

declare var AnyJS: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})

export class HomePage {

    private anyjs : any;
    private method : any;

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
        this.anyjs = new AnyJS();
        this.method = this.anyjs.methodCall();
    }

}
```

And, here is my AnyJS file:

```
function AnyJS(){}

AnyJS.prototype.methodCall = function() {
    console.log("Done!");
    return true;
};
```

Note: AnyJS file contains an object with some properties and methods which doesn't comply with the latest ES6 standards but plain JS methods. I need to create an object and call the methods directly from my `home.ts`.

Answer (score 2):

Change your AnyJs file to something like this:

```
export class AnyJs {

  public methodCall () {
    console.log('done');
    return true;
  }

}
```

Then in your `home.ts` file import it:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

import { AnyJs } from './anyjs.ts'; // or the path of the file

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})

export class HomePage {

    constructor(
      public navCtrl: NavController,
      public anyJs: AnyJs) {
        this.anyJs = anyJs; 
        // And then you can use it anywhere in your file like:
        this.anyJs.methodCall().success(data => console.log(data));
    }

}
```

Now if your AnyJs file is an ES6 file you have those options:

Declare a module and export the class to use:

```
declare module "foo" { export class Foo{ } }
```

Or Declare function as a module

```
export default function () { ... };


import myFunc from 'AnyJs';
myFunc();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But, do I need to rewrite the functions in the external js in TypeScript? Is there any other solution for importing my js file as it is without rewriting in TypeScript?

Comment: You can declare a module with es6: `declare module "foo" {
    export class Foo{ }
}` for example.

Comment: Could be please explain this as well? Because I want to import my js file as it is without rewriting in TypeScript.

Comment: Thanks. I updated my question. So, basically I want to call the methods of AnyJS file directly from my `home.ts`. Is there any other alternative? If not, what would be the best approach?

Comment: Still getting the error: **Cannot find name 'AnyJs'**. 
 `constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public anyJs: AnyJs) {`

Comment: Did you imported it?

Comment: Yes, I imported it as explained in the answer. The import statement is not recognised either. The best approach which was suggested was to make an `npm` module of the same and then import it like other `npm` modules.